# Как очистить разом группу lineEdit?

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, qlineedit, findchildren

Можно ли как-то оптимизировать подобный код?

```
    self.lineEdit_2.clear()
    self.lineEdit_3.clear()
    self.lineEdit_4.clear()
    self.lineEdit_5.clear()
    self.lineEdit_6.clear()
    self.lineEdit_7.clear()
    self.lineEdit_8.clear()
    self.lineEdit_9.clear()
    self.lineEdit_10.clear()
    self.lineEdit_11.clear()
    self.lineEdit_12.clear()
    self.lineEdit_13.clear()
    self.lineEdit_14.clear()
    self.lineEdit_15.clear()
    self.lineEdit_16.clear()
    self.lineEdit_17.clear()
    self.lineEdit_18.clear()
    self.lineEdit_19.clear()
    self.lineEdit_20.clear()
    self.lineEdit_21.clear()
    self.lineEdit_22.clear()
    self.lineEdit_23.clear()
    self.lineEdit_24.clear()
    self.lineEdit_25.clear()
    self.lineEdit_26.clear()
    self.lineEdit_27.clear()
    self.lineEdit_28.clear()
    self.lineEdit_29.clear()
    self.lineEdit_30.clear()
    self.lineEdit_31.clear()
    self.lineEdit_32.clear()
    self.lineEdit_33.clear()
```

Понимаю, что для асов это всё элементарно, но я недавно в Python, прошу не судить строго))

Comment: почитайте о списках(`list`), либо о словорях (`dict`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QWidget, QGridLayout, QPushButton, 
    QLineEdit, QApplication)

class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        grid_layout = QGridLayout(self)

        for x in range(7):
            for y in range(5):                
                lineEdit = QLineEdit(str(str(5*x+y)))
                grid_layout.addWidget(lineEdit, x, y)
                
        pushButton = QPushButton('Click me')
        pushButton.clicked.connect(self.pushButton_clicked)
        grid_layout.addWidget(pushButton, x+1, 0, 1, 5)
                
    def pushButton_clicked(self):
        lineEdits = self.findChildren(QLineEdit)                        # !!!
        for le in lineEdits:
            le.clear()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]